# Importing apklib from github with Maven

Tags: android, facebook, maven, github, repository

I am trying to use the Facebook Android SDK within my Maven Android application. For this I used a custom maven repo (https://github.com/avianey/facebook-api-android-maven). I noticed the Android Support package was outdated, and created my own github repo (it is exactly the same project, except for the pom). This worked for a while. However, when my team members wanted to import the maven dependencies, it threw some exceptions.

```
Error when importing module '~apklib-com.github.bertdecock_facebook-android-ahoy-api_3.0.0': Cannot find file C:\Users\Bert\.m2\repository\com\github\bertdecock\facebook-android-ahoy-api\3.0.0\facebook-android-ahoy-api-3.0.0.apklib
17:19:50 Error when importing module '~apklib-com.github.bertdecock_facebook-android-ahoy-api_3.0.0': Cannot find file C:\Users\Bert\.m2\repository\com\github\bertdecock\facebook-android-ahoy-api\3.0.0\facebook-android-ahoy-api-3.0.0.apklib
17:19:50 Error when importing module '~apklib-com.github.bertdecock_facebook-android-ahoy-api_3.0.0': Cannot find src directory in C:/Users/Bert/Development/IntelliJ Projects/SDProject/AndroidApp/gen-external-apklibs/com.github.bertdecock_facebook-android-ahoy-api_3.0.0
```

I deleted the apklib from my local repository, and noticed it wouldn't import anymore. I don't know why it worked the first time.

This is what I used in my pom to import the original project:

```
<repositories>  
  ...  
  <repository>  
    <id>The mavenized Facebook Android API</id>  
    <url>http://avianey.github.com/facebook-api-android-maven/</url>  
  </repository>  
</repositories>

...

<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.avianey</groupId>
    <artifactId>facebook-android-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And this is how I imported my own custom project (https://github.com/bertdecock/facebook-android-ahoy-api):

```
<repository>
    <id>The mavenized Facebook Android API</id>
    <url>https://github.com/bertdecock/facebook-android-ahoy-api/</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.bertdecock</groupId>
    <artifactId>facebook-android-ahoy-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

When I restore the old apklib in my local repository, it works just fine. Delete it, and it stops working.

However, when I try to update my dependencies, maven does find the facebook project pom and puts it in my local repository.

Any suggestions on why this is happening (and on how to fix it) would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleteing all `_maven.repositories` files from your local maven repository. 
They hold the information about the origin of the artefacts.

Maven tries to update your jar from the old location (as saved in _maven.repositories) and fails. The presumtion here is that the same aftifact on a different remote repository might be different.

To delete all `_maven.repositories` you can use this command:

```
find ~/.m2/ -name _maven.repositories | xargs rm
```